# JavaScript: Why is this causing an infinite loop?

Tags: javascript, algorithm, bit-manipulation, integer-overflow

I'm trying to find the largest number by finding the point at which the JavaScript number line wraps around. E.g., if it could only hold numbers `0, 1, 127` then I'd find `127` by using the fact that "`127 + 1 = 0`". So I made a function

```
function getLargestNumber ( ) 
{
   var somethingBig = 12939123, last = (somethingBig - 1);
   while ( ++somethingBig > ++last );
   return last;
}
```

but that's causing an infinite loop (or crashing the browser for some other reason).

Is there anything wrong with the logic of my function?

Answer (score 2):

JavaScript numbers are always stored as floating point numbers, not integers like in C.  Floating point numbers don't "wrap around" the same way that a C integer will.

This might help you [What is JavaScript's highest integer value that a Number can go to without losing precision?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/307179/what-is-javascripts-highest-integer-value-that-a-number-can-go-to-without-losin)

Comment: It should eventually stop when the numbers get so large that the precision doesn't include the lowest digit.

Comment: @Barmar if it eventually stops, then should I be looking for the point at which `somethingBig + 1 = somethingBig`?

Comment: True, but that's not the largest value that a JavaScript number can be.  It's just the largest number before integer precision starts getting lost.

Comment: @SubparWebDev Correct. At 1 million iterations/sec, that will take about 285 years.

Comment: @SubparWebDev What are you trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the while loop will run forever because you are always incrementing both somethingBig and last, therefore somethingBig will always be larger:

```
while ( ++somethingBig > ++last );
```

I'm not sure exactly what you are trying to accomplish but this would be the cause of the infinite loop.

Hope this helps!

Comment: He's expecting `somethingBig` to overflow and wrap around to 0 before `last` does.

Comment: @Barmar Not necessarily to zero ... maybe to the smallest negative number.

Comment: Thanks @Barmar, unfortunately it's taking a little longer than expected :)

Comment: @SubparWebDev Right, I was thinking of unsigned numbers.